# Drupal 6 - ignore required form field

Tags: forms, validation, drupal, drupal-6

I need to ignore the validation of two form field while creating a user in Drupal 6 but I don't know at all how to do :

```
  $userinfo = array(
    'name' => $login,
    'init' => $mail,
    'mail' => $mail,
    'pass' => $password,
    'status' => 1,
    'lastname' => "", //how to ignore those required fields that invalidate the form
    'surname' => ""   //how to ignore those required fields that invalidate the form
  );

  // register a new user
  $form_state = array();
  $form_state['values'] = $userinfo;
  drupal_execute('user_register', $form_state);
  $errors = form_get_errors(); // getting 2 required field errors
```

Note that I can't supress the "required" property as it is used elsewhere in a more "complex" form.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't ask 2 questions in one; if you have two questions, ask two separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't got a D6 site handy to test this on but I think it'll work...

Since `drupal_execute()` pushes you through the whole form build process you can take advantage of [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) to remove the required status, but only in a context you pass along in the `$form_state`. For example

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register' && !empty($form_state['custom_execution'])) {
    $form['lastname']['#required'] = FALSE;
    // etc...
  }
}

...

$form_state = array();
$form_state['values'] = $userinfo;
$form_state['custom_execution'] = TRUE;
drupal_execute('user_register', $form_state);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) to supress the "required" property, only when the from is not used in its "complex" form?

For instance, if you know what paths the "complex" form is used, you can check if that paths is being served with [arg](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/arg/6).

Better checks may be available...